# Sherlock: The Abominable Bride DVD/Blu-ray and extra scenes

Tags: sherlock, alternate-version

1. People who have watched the special episode in theaters have (presumably) enjoyed 20-25 minutes of additional footage. Did this footage contain extra scenes, or was it behind-the-scenes footage?
2. Did said footage appear in the DVD/Blu-ray release of the special episode? (Which was released yesterday on Amazon, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

[A reporter at Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/scottmendelson/2016/01/07/i-paid-35-to-see-sherlock-the-abominable-bride-in-theaters/) has (part of) the answer:

> Okay, yes there were **around 20 minutes of “behind the scenes” footage**,
>   including an amusing “random set details you probably missed”
>   featurette, that will presumably end up on the DVD/Blu Ray release,
>   but **less than the estimated 70 minutes or so of documentary material
>   that will end up on said DVD/Blu-Ray release** next Tuesday and via
>   online download/streaming purchase this very morning for the price of
>   a single movie ticket.

[According to Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013JBJ7EG) these are the extras:

> - Mark Gatiss: A Study in Sherlock – 30-minute "making of" documentary
> - Mark Gatiss: Production Diary
> - Creating the Look – Eight inside looks into how different scenes were created in the Sherlock Special
> - Interview with the writers Steven Moffat and Mark Gatiss
> - Sherlockology Q&A